# Starling Framework Centralise all touch events of my game

Tags: android, actionscript-3, touch, movieclip, starling-framework

I have a main level 1 class and loads of images, sprites and movieclips as children of level 1.

```
/**
 * @desc This handles any touch event interactions in the level
 * @param   event
 */

private function touchInteractionHandler(event:TouchEvent):void {

    //register event listeners for touches
    var touchBegan:Touch = event.getTouch(this, TouchPhase.BEGAN);
    var touchEnded:Touch = event.getTouch(this, TouchPhase.ENDED);
    var touchHover:Touch = event.getTouch(this, TouchPhase.HOVER);

    //listen for touches that have just ended
    if (touchEnded) {

        if ( touchEnded.tapCount == 2 ) {

            //get object touched
            var object = event.target;

            //check if player is in walking range. if so then walk to that position of touch.globalx and y
            playerWalkCheck(touchEnded.globalX, touchEnded.globalY);
        }

    }
}
```

I want to centralize my touches in the game. Instead of having multiple listeners on all movieclips on the stage I want the main touch event to listen for what was touched.

e.g. There is a dog called Bob on the stage when I double tap on him it will call the method touchInteractionHandler() above.

I know how to get the movieclip object and trace it out:

```
trace(event.target);

[object MovieClip]
```

I just cannot seem to know how to identify the name of the movieclip so I can then do the following (pseudo)

```
if movieclip is bob ->
   //do something with bob
else if movieclip is charlie ->
  //do something wit charlie
else ->
  make player walk to a position e.g. playerWalkCheck(touchEnded.globalX, touchEnded.globalY);
```

This is a real burden on my game project and a solution would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I approached the problem with having multiple Feathers Buttons (they are derived from MovieClips, the principle is the same for plain MovieClips) on screen, and not wanting to have a separate listener for each. When creating objects, each sends touches to the same event listener. Then I have a Vector where I stuff all the buttons after creation:

```
private var vBtns:Vector.<Button>;
```

In the listener I have:

```
private function onBtnTouch(e:starling.events.Event):void
{
    var idxButton:int=vBtns.indexOf(e.currentTarget);
    doSomething(idxButton);//or vBtns[idxButton].something()
}
```

The same system can easily be extended to handle other types of objects that dispatch Touch events.

From what I understand you tried something similar and it didn't work. Did you use the correct Event type (starling.events.Event, not the old Flash touch event)?

Comment: yes I did find a workaround. In the main class just added a main listener. Whenever any of the separate objects were touched they would dispatch a custom event that would pass the params of the object that sent it.